# Customize object serialization to Json in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization, json.net

I am making an asp.net core web api and i want to return Ok(JsonList) in a specific format
I have a list of the following object:

```
public class obj 
{ 
  string schoolName;
  int studentscount;
  int teacherscount;
}
```

that would be serialized by default to:

```
[{"schoolName":"name_1",
  "studentscount" : "5",
  "teacherscount" : "2"
 },
{"schoolName":"name_2",
  "studentscount" : "10",
  "teacherscount" : "3"
 }]
```

I want the name property to be the name of the object :

```
    [{
   "name_1":{
      "studentscount" : "5",
      "teacherscount" : "2"
     },
    "name_2:"{
      "studentscount" : "10",
      "teacherscount" : "3"
     }
   }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new class and try this

```
    Dictionary<string, Counts> counts = JArray.Parse(json).ToDictionary(j => (string)j["schoolName"], j => new Counts
    {
        studentscount = (int)j["studentscount"],
        teacherscount = (int)j["teacherscount"]
    });

    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(counts, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

public class Counts
{
    public int studentscount { get; set; }
    public int teacherscount { get; set; }
}
```

result

```
{
  "name_1": {
    "studentscount": 5,
    "teacherscount": 2
  },
  "name_2": {
    "studentscount": 10,
    "teacherscount": 3
  }
}
```

but if for some reasons you still need an array

```
var countsArray = new List<Dictionary<string,Counts>> {counts};

json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(countsArray,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

result

```
[
  {
    "name_1": {
      "studentscount": 5,
      "teacherscount": 2
    },
    "name_2": {
      "studentscount": 10,
      "teacherscount": 3
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: what is the json inside Pars() ?

Comment: Bear in mind that if `schoolName` for any reason is not unique/distinct you will have some issues when working with a dictionary. If its unique, and especially if you intend to look up by that school name string, then use a Dictionary

Comment: @Hyroglatos_7700 The first json is inside of Parse(), the second json is a result. If you need it or  maybe you can return a c# object. You have to post the code you are using  if you have some problems.